# Non-zero coefficients of primitive polynomials

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $R$ be the finite field with $q$ elements, and let $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$
be positive integers $\geq 2$. I want to prove that there exists a primitive 
polynomial $$F(x) = x^{mn}-\sum\limits_{j=0}^{mn-1}f_jx^j\in R[x]$$
with the property that there is a $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $f_{km}\neq 0$.
I think that this is always true except in case $q=m=n=2$.

Comment: There is an extensive literature on prescribing coefficients of primitive polynomials of many authors, for instance, S. D. Cohen has several papers on the subject with extensive bibliography.

Comment: Thank you, very much. It follows from the  Hansen-Mullen conjecture proved in 2007.

Comment: can you add an answer explaining this?

Comment: [Cross posted to Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1717075/11619).

Comment: @ Lior Bary-Soroker, I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post here a Hansen-Mullen's conjecture, which was proved in 2007. The validity of my assumption in the question is a straightforward consequence of this conjecture.

**Conjecture**.(Hansen and Mullen, 1992)
*Let $a\in \mathbb{F}_q$ and let $n\geq2$ be a positive integer. Fix and integer $m$ with $0<m<n$. Then there exists a primitive polynomial $f(x) = x^n
+\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jx^{n-j}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $a_m = a$ with (genuine) exceptions when*
$$
(q,n,m,a) = (q,2,1,0), (4,3,1,0), (4,3,2,0), (2,4,2,1).
$$
The proof is carried out in several stages. See for details Stephen D Cohen,  [Primitive polynomials with a prescribed coefficient](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1071579705000663), Finite Fields and Their Applications 12 (2006) 425-491. The completion of the proof is given in Cohen and Presern, The Hansen-Mullen primitivity conjecture: completion of proof, in McKee and Smyth, eds.,  [Number Theory and Polynomials](http://www.cambridge.org/ru/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/number-theory-and-polynomials), London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series 352.

Comment: Reference for the proof?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, I have added refferences.